# operator overloading c++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, friend

I am trying to preform  operator overloading in C++;
for some reason the compiles keeps on giving me the error

> error: ‘bool Matrix::operator==(const Matrix&, const Matrix&)’ must take exactly one argument

Now, I know that there is some way to to it with one argument using this, but I understood that by using friend I can do it this way, but it still is not working.

Here is my code,

Thanks in advance.

```
class Matrix{
public:
 Matrix();
 friend bool operator==(Matrix &mtrx1,Matrix &mtrx2);
 friend bool operator!=(Matrix &mtrx1,Matrix &mtrx2);

protected:
 std::vector<Cell> _matrix;
 int _row;
 int _col;

};

inline bool Matrix::operator==(const Matrix& mtrx1, const Matrix& mtrx2){

/* .......... */
}
```

Comment: To format the code nicely, indent it with 4 spaces, or select it and press the button with 0s and 1s on it.

Answer (score 8):

The `operator==` **member** function is declared as:

```
class foo {
  public:
    bool operator==( foo const & rhs ) const;
};
```

The `operator==` **global** function is declared as:

```
bool operator==( foo const & lhs, foo const & rhs );
```

---

<strike>Generally, the member function is declared and defined first. Then, the global function is defined in terms of the member function as</strike>

Only one between the member function and global function is declared and defined. Having both of them is ambiguous for statements like (1) in the following

```
foo f1;
foo f2;
bool f1EqualsF2 = (f1 == f2 );  // (1), ambiguous
```

and in such cases compiler returns error. In g++, the error message looks like

```
equals.cpp:24: error: ambiguous overload for ‘operator==’ in ‘f1 == f2’
equals.cpp:8: note: candidates are: bool foo::operator==(const foo&) const
equals.cpp:17: note:                 bool operator==(const foo&, const foo&)
```

---

Whenever `operator==` is done, its recommended to do the corresponding `operator!=`.

Comment: Don't forget the const on the method operator==()

Comment: This is wrong. Generally you either define a member function _or_ you define a free function. You shouldn't define both otherwise `a == b` will generally be ambiguous. A free function is usually preferred as it leads to consistent implicit conversion rules for both left and right operands. As it stands you can't do `lhs.operator==( rhs )` as `operator==` is a non-`const` member function and is `private` in `foo`.

Comment: Thanks to Martin York and Charles Bailey (+1 to them); I made some corrections in the answer (added `const` in member function, and `public` qualifier).

Comment: You've edited, but you have still left in the suggestion that you have both a member `operator==` and a global `operator==` (one implemented in terms of the other). This is not correct because it will make `a == b` ambiguous where `a` and `b` are both `foo`.

Answer (score 5):

Although you've put the `friend` declaration inside the class, it's not a member. So the function definition should be a non-member:

```
inline bool operator==(const Matrix& mtrx1, const Matrix& mtrx2) {...}
```

You also need to add `const` qualifiers to the arguments of the declarations, to match those in the definition.

Comment: Note, however, that the `friend` declaration forces it to be a non-member, so even if you define it in-place inside the class definition, it'll really be a global function!

Comment: @Jerry Coffin: or, more strictly, a function belonging to the innermost namespace enclosing the given class.

Answer (score 3):

```
class Matrix{
public:
    Matrix();
    friend bool operator==(const Matrix &mtrx1, const Matrix &mtrx2);
    friend bool operator!=(const Matrix &mtrx1, const Matrix &mtrx2);

protected:
    std::vector<Cell> _matrix;
    int _row;
    int _col;
};

inline bool operator==(const Matrix& mtrx1, const Matrix& mtrx2){
    /* .......... */
    return true;
}
```

Pass compilation in Visual Studio 2005.

1. omit the const qualifier in your friend declaration
2. don't need Matrix:: in operation== definition

Answer (score 1):

You do it with 2 parameters if you are doing it outside of the class, not as a member function.

As a member function you need only 1 parameter (the other parameter is `*this`)

Comment: ...and you won't need friend if you implement as part of the class